# Right triangle inside circle

Tags: circles, triangles

I know $a$, $b$, $c$, $x_1$, $y_1$, $\alpha_1$. I want to move the point with distance ($d$) and then calculate $x_2$, $y_2$, $\alpha_2$.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you have enough information to do that. I think you need to know $c$ as well...

Comment: Is the $d$ measured along the arc, as you diagram implies?

Comment: @amd Yes, "d"  is measured along the arc

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have enough information for that, you would need $c$ too (or something to calculate $c$).

The point is that the angle that you rotates the triangle is the difference between $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_1$. You find that by the fact that $\sin{\alpha_2-\alpha_1\over 2} = {d\over 2c}$. Then you use simple trigonometrics to find $x_2$ and $y_2$.

Comment: I know a,b,c. I've edited my question

Comment: Nope, it didn't help me. a2 = a1 + c*d ? This can't be an angle. And if i found a2, how to find x2=x1+? and y2=y1+?

Comment: @VasilNikolov You're missing the $\sin$.

Comment: It looks to me like $d$ is measured along the arc.

Comment: @amd Unfortunately the picture didn't use a large enough $d$ to clearly show the difference. In that case the arc angle would be $d/c$.